# ¿como firmar digitalmente un pdf con php (symfony2)?

Tags: php, symfony2, pdf

Buen día.
Mi pregunta es como puedo firmar digitalmente un archivo pdf (o que librerías debo utilizar).
Estoy trabajando bajo el framework php symfony2.
De antemano gracias.

Comment: Symfony2 propiamente tal no firma, sino que debe firmar el package/bundle/librería que uses para crear el PDF

Answer (score 1):

Tienes la extensión apropiada en el propio PHP. Puedes consultar la sección del manual oficial para más detalles: http://php.net/manual/es/book.openssl.php

A modo de ejemplo te hago un corta y pega de uno de los ejemplos que he visto en el propio manual y te explican como firmar un archivo (en este caso es un txt pero podría ser un pdf o un png o cualquier otro).

```
<?php
// el mensaje que quiere firmar, por lo que el destinatario puede estar serguro de fue usted
// el que lo envió
$data = <<<EOD

Tiene mi autorización para emplear $10,000 en gastos de comida.

El Presidente
EOD;
// guardar el mensaje en un archivo
$fp = fopen("mensaje.txt", "w");
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
// encriptarlo
if (openssl_pkcs7_sign("mensaje.txt", "firmado.txt", "micert.pem",
    array("file://micert.pem", "mi_frase_de_contraseña"),
    array("Para" => "joes@example.com", // sintaxis asociativa
          "DE: C.G. <presidente@example.com>", // sintaxis indexada
          "Tema" => "Confidencial")
    )) {
    // mensaje firmado - ¡envíelo!
    exec(ini_get("ruta_correo") . " < firmado.txt");
}
?>
```

Al usar Symfony deberías usar la lógica dentro del Controlador que gestione la firma de los archivos.

Si buscas un bundle que encapsule esta funcionalidad (yo no le veo mucho sentido) he encontrado uno en packagist, pero no parece muy usuado ni actualizado: https://packagist.org/packages/rc/openssl-crypto-bundle